# Using Presto on Cloud Dataproc with Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I use both Hive and MySQL (via [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)) and I want to use [Presto](http://prestodb.io) to connect to both easily. I have seen there is a [Presto initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/presto) for Cloud Dataproc but it does not work with Cloud SQL out of the box. How can I get that initialization action to work with Cloud SQL so I can use both Hive/Spark and Cloud SQL with Presto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to edit the initialization action installing Presto on the Cloud Dataproc cluster.

**Cloud SQL setup**

Before you do this, however, make sure to configure Cloud SQL so it will work with Presto. You will need to:

1. Create a user for Presto (or have a user ready)
2. Adjust any necessary firewall rules so your Cloud Dataproc cluster can connect to the Cloud SQL instance

**Changing the initialization action**

In the Presto initialization action there is a section which sets up the Hive configuration and looks like this:

```
cat > presto-server-${PRESTO_VERSION}/etc/catalog/hive.properties <<EOF
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
EOF
```

You can add a new section like this (below) which sets up the mysql properties. Add something like this:

```
cat > presto-server-${PRESTO_VERSION}/etc/catalog/mysql.properties <<EOF
connector.name=mysql
connection-url=jdbc:mysql://<ip_address>:3306
connection-user=<username>
connection-password=<password>
EOF
```

You will obviously want to replace `<ip_address>`, `<username>`, and `<password>` with your correct values. Moreover, if you have **multiple** Cloud SQL instances to connect to, you can add multiple sections and give them different names, so long as the filename ends in `.properties`.